# Python и FFmpeg: создать видео с аудио за один проход или иначе ускорить процесс

Tags: python, windows, ffmpeg, видео

пытаюсь подружить Python и FFmpeg под Windows.

Необходимо из набора изображений и звуковых дорожек (хранятся в памяти программы как numpy array) сделать одно длинное видео.

Смог сделать это в 2 прохода:

- сначала создаю видео файл без аудио дорожки,
- потом прибавляю к нему аудио, но хотелось бы оптимальнее и быстрее:

```
ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt bgr24 -r 5.00 ^
       -i pipe:0 -an -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -pix_fmt yuv420p video.avi
```

- создаю видео

```
ffmpeg -y -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 44100 -ac 1 ^
       -i pipe:0 -i video.avi -c:v h264 -c:a ac3 videoANDaudio.avi
```

- добавляю аудио.

Можно ли сделать это в 1 проход? Т.е. как то надо передавать видео и аудио одновременно, в 2 потока. Думал о NamedPipe, но не нашел в интернете информацию о том, как его создать в Windows.

PS. Предложите технологию, лучше FFmpeg, для решения задачи, если такая имеется.

Answer (score 7):

## Про обработку видео в Python

> PS. Предложите технологию, лучше FFMpeg для решения задачи, если такая
>   имеется.

### PyAV

Есть такой замечаетельный проект: [PyAV](http://mikeboers.github.io/PyAV/).
Это питонячие биндинги к `libav`. 
Для работы с видео в Python я использую его. 
АPI PyAV сильно не совпадает с аргументами `ffmpeg` и ванильного libav,
но при этом оно кажется весьма понятным и логичным в контексте Python.

#### PyAV: Пример

https://gist.github.com/w495/7d843bd5d42fc35e15486ec60a87d9bf

```py
import av
from av.video.frame import VideoFrame
from av.video.stream import VideoStream

# В этом списке будем хранить кадры в виде numpy-векторов.
array_list = []

# Откроем контейнер на чтение
input_container = av.open('input.mp4')

# Применим «инверсное мультиплексирование» =)
# Получим пакеты из потока.
input_packets = input_container.demux()

# Получии все кадры видео и положим их в `array_list`.
for packet in input_packets:
    if isinstance(packet.stream, VideoStream):
        # Получим все кадры пакета
        frames = packet.decode()
        for raw_frame in frames:
            # Переформатируем кадры, к нужному размеру и виду.
            # Это лучше делать средствами pyav (libav)
            #   потому что быстрее.
            frame = raw_frame.reformat(32, 32, 'rgb24')
            # Превратить каждый кадр в numpy-вектор (dtype=int).
            array = frame.to_nd_array()
            # Положим в список numpy-векторов.
            array_list += [array]

# Откроем контейнер на запись.
output_container = av.open('out.mp4', mode='w', format='mp4')

# Добавим к контейнеру поток c кодеком h264.
output_stream = output_container.add_stream('h264', rate=25)

# В этом списке будем хранить пакеты выходного потока.
output_packets = []

# Пройдем по списку векторов и упакуем их в пакеты выходного протока.
for array in array_list:
    # Построим видео-кадр по вектору.
    frame = VideoFrame.from_ndarray(array, format='rgb24')
    # Запакуем полученный кадр.
    packet = output_stream.encode(frame)
    # Положим в список пакетов.
    output_packets += [packet]

# Применим «прямое мультиплексирование» =)
# Для каждого пакета вызовем мультиплексор.
for packet in output_packets:
    if packet:
        output_container.mux(packet)

output_container.close()
```

Еще примеры:

- [encode_frames.py](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyAV/blob/2ba8cf7162e0c21ff208ca5df8e6b69abe80feff/examples/encode_frames.py) — создает видео из последовательности переданных изображений; для работы с изображениями использует OpenCV. На самом деле, тут можно обойтись и без OpenCV.
- [gen_rgb_rotate.py](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyAV/blob/2ba8cf7162e0c21ff208ca5df8e6b69abe80feff/examples/gen_rgb_rotate.py) — создает видео, в котором цвет кадра меняется в последовательности цветов радуги.
- [encode.py](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyAV/blob/2ba8cf7162e0c21ff208ca5df8e6b69abe80feff/examples/encode.py) — записывает кадры исходного видео, до тех пор пока, их количество видео-кадров не превысит `100`.

Сам я активно использую *PyAV* в этом проекте: [Video Shot Detector](https://github.com/w495/python-video-shot-detector).
Возможно, в его коде будет что-то полезное для Вас.

https://github.com/w495/python-video-shot-detector

#### PyAV: Установка

Есть маленькая проблема в том, что PyAV достаточно [тяжело собрать](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/mikeboers/pyav/build/1.0.98/job/9oqql94ogk48i8p9). Тем более под Windows. 
Для сборки из исходников требуются конкретные версии зависимостей (`ffmpeg`, `h264` и пр.) Но есть уже готовые сборки для питонячьего пакетного менеджера [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/intro.html). 
Я не пробовал, но кажется достаточно просто поставить `conda` на Windows:

1. Выбираете нужный вам инсталлятор тут: [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html). Я предполагаю что это будет `Python 2.7 64-bit (exe installer)`
2. Дальше запускаете и следуете его инструкциям.
3. Далее как описано в [Windows Miniconda Install](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/install/quick.html#windows-miniconda-install) в командной строке Windows `conda list .`
4. После этого вам потребуется поставить нужные пакеты.

```bsh
conda install numpy
conda install -c danielballan pyav
# или conda install -c soft-matter pyav
```

Я не уверен, что это все заведется под Windows — я не пробовал. 
Если нет, то на официальном сайте есть инcтрукция как собрать самостоятельно:

- [PyAV Installation On Windows](https://mikeboers.github.io/PyAV/installation.html#on-windows);
- `+` еще есть вот такая заметка [PyAV for Windows](https://griffeltavla.wordpress.com/2015/04/11/pyav-for-windows/).

Авторы библиотеки весьма отзывчивы, и им можно смело задавать вопросы и писать о проблемах тут: [PyAV Issues](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyAV/issues).

### Альтернативы

Из альтернатив, еще наталкивался на

- [Avpy](https://avpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) — просто биндинг к `ffmpeg` и `libav`;
- [pyffmpeg](https://mhaller.github.io/pyffmpeg/) — тоже биндинг к `ffmpeg`;
- [ffmpeg-cffi-py](https://github.com/firodj/ffmpeg-cffi-py) — еще один биндинг, работает только на Windows;
- [pyVideoInput](https://github.com/pupil-labs/pyvideoinput) — используют свой обработчик видео без `ffmpeg`, выглядит он слишком заморочено;
- [Python GStreamer](https://habrahabr.ru/post/178813/) — используют свой обработчик видео, пока не осилил, но при беглом осмотре, выглядит удобным;
- [Python OpenCV](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) — обработка видео через **OpenCV** изначально похожа на забивание гвоздей микроскопом;
- [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html) — библиотека для не линейного монтажа видео, но кодировать ей тоже можно. Отчасти тоже забивание гвоздей микроскопом.

Про Python GStreamer:

- [Using GStreamer with Python](https://markwingerd.wordpress.com/2014/11/19/using-gstreamer-with-python/);
- [Getting started with GStreamer with Python](http://www.jonobacon.org/2006/08/28/getting-started-with-gstreamer-with-python/);
- [Python GStreamer Tutorial](http://brettviren.github.io/pygst-tutorial-org/pygst-tutorial.html).

#### Качество альтернатив

- *Avpy* у меня почему-то так и не завелся.
- *pyffmpeg* тоже сходу не собирается, а перед началом установки приходится править код.
- *ffmpeg-cffi-py* не смог найти путей до нужных библиотек.
- Остальные пока не пробовал.

Answer (score 6):

## Про FFMpeg

### Кратко

> Можно ли сделать это в 1 проход

Можно. Для этого нужно `ffmpeg` в одной команде передать и звук и видео.
Это легко делается, если просто исходной команде передать еще один входной поток

```bsh
ffmpeg 
    -f rawvideo -codec:v rawvideo 
        -s 1920x1080 
        -pix_fmt bgr24 
        -r 5.00 
        -i pipe:0 # video 
    -f s16le -codec:a pcm_s16le 
        -ar 44100 
        -ac 1 
        -i pipe:0 # audio 
    -codec:v libx264 
        -preset medium 
        -pix_fmt yuv420p 
    -codec:a ac3
```

Но проблема в том, что вы посылаете ему изображения и семплы через `stdin (pipe:0)`. Самым простым решением было бы:

1. Записать изображения из Вашей программы в один файл.
2. Семплы записать в другой файл.

   - *причем эти действия можно совершать параллельно (`multiprocessing`)*;
3. Оба файла скормить как `-i filename`.

Предполагаю, что это будет работать быстрее.

> но хотелось бы оптимальнее и быстрее.

Для FFmpeg ключ `-threads` со значением `0` позволяет работаеть многопоточно, и распределять вычисления по всем процессорам.

### Много букв

У `ffmpeg` есть некоторая особенность — можно передавать много одноименных аргументов. Причем порядок этих аргументов имеет значение. Во многих случаях эта особенность не очень заментна. Но в какой-то момент сильно выстреливает.

Порядок аргументов подчиняется следуюшей логике.

1. Параметры входных потоков

   - сначала общие:

     - формат, смещение по времени и пр, что-то типа:

       - `-ss '00:05:00'` — кодировать с пятой минуты.
   - потом раздельные:

     - видео, аудио, субтитры:

       - `-f rawvideo -codec:v rawvideo ...`;
       - `-f s16le -codec:a pcm_s16le  ...`;
2. Параметры выходных потоков

   - сначала раздельные:

     - видео, аудио, субтитры:

       - `-codec:v 'libx264' -profile:v 'main' -b:v '1000k' -filter:v "yadif=1:-1:0,scale=0:576"`;
       - `-strict 'experimental' -codec:a 'aac' -b:a '196k' -ac '6'`.
   - потом общие:
     смещение по времени, формат контейнера и пр, что-то типа:
         * -ss '00:05:01' -to '00:05:30' 
         * `-movflags '+faststart' -f 'mp4' -y file_name.mp4`

При соблюдении этой логики можно будет в одной команде собирать,
видео более чем из одного потока. 
И даже больше чем в один поток: [Creating Multiple Outputs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs).

У меня под рукой есть несколько примеров (из [Bulk Video Converter](https://github.com/w495/bulk-video-converter)). Кажется, что запись видео с экрана и аудио с микрофона очень похожа на вашу ситуацию.

```bsh
/usr/bin/ffmpeg                                     \
    -threads '0'                                    \
    -f x11grab                                      \
        -s wxga                                     \
        -i ':0.0'                                   \
    -f alsa                                         \
        -i hw:0                                     \
    -codec:v 'libx264'                              \
        -profile:v 'main'                           \
        -b:v '1000k'                                \
        -filter:v "yadif=1:-1:0,scale=0:576"        \
    -codec:a 'libmp3lame'                           \
        -b:a '196k'                                 \
    -f 'mp4' -y 'video_pal_sd.mp4'                  \
```

На *nix это работает. Предполагаю, что на Windows будет работать с точностью до имен кодеров. Я не до конца понимаю, вашу задачу, потому тут сейчас распишу, что означает каждый из аргументов.

Настройки входных потоков:

1. Входное видео:

   - `-f x11grab` — формат аудио, в моем случае — название драйвера;
   - `-s wxga` — размер входного видео-кадра, тут мы говорим ffmpeg как воспринимать, то что мы его передаем — в моем случае: размер моего монитора —
   - `-i ':0.0'` — тут, номер дисплея, но возомжен любой иной источник;
2. Входное аудио:

   - `-f 'alsa` — формат аудио, в моем случае — название драйвера аудио-карты;
   - `-i 'hw:0'` — тут, аудио-карты (входной поток — т.е. микрофон), но возможен любой иной источник;

Настройки результирующих потоков:

3. Результирующее видео:

   - `-codec:v 'libx264'` — определяем кодек, которым будем кодировать видео (`h264`).
   - `-profile:v 'main'` — профиль кодирования для h264.
   - `-b:v '1000k'` — битрейт для видео-потока.
   - `-filter:v "yadif=1:-1:0,scale=0:576"` — фильтры для видео-потока:

     - `yadif=1:-1:0` — убирает чересстрочность;
     - `scale=0:576` — приводит выходной видео-поток к ножному размеру — этот размер никак не соотносится с размером входного потока.
4. Результирующее аудио:

   - `-codec:a 'libmp3lame'` — определяем кодек, которым будем кодировать аудио (`mp3`).
   - `-b:a '196k'` — битрейт для аудио-потока.

Настройки результирующего файла (контейнера):
* `-f 'mp4'` — формат, можно не указывать, и тогда `ffmpeg` попробует «догадаться» сам;
* `-y 'video_pal_sd.mp4'` — флаг перезаписи `-y` и имя выходного файла.

Comment: Разбил на 2 комментария, чтобы было проще воспринимать.
Продолжение тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551625/203032