# Как организовать рестрим rtmp?

Tags: php, python, потоки-данных, streaming, rtmp

У меня есть rtmp поток и rtmp сервер, на который нужно отправить этот поток с определенным именем. Как лучше всего это можно организовать?(желательно на php или python, хотя можно и со сторонними утилитами)

Comment: У плеера VLC есть отличная функция потоковой передачи, только rtmp  поток до ютуба я так и не смог допихать.

Comment: попробуй поковырять исходники https://github.com/qwantix/php-rtmp-client

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, сервер, принимает только RTMP? Не лучше ли будет делать рестрим по HTTP? Что это за сервер.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Cо сторонними утилитами

Подобного проще всего достичь с помощью FFMpeg:

```bash
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -re \
    -i 'rtmp://src_stream:1935/play' \
    -vcodec copy -acodec copy \
    -f flv 'rtmp://dst_stream:1935/publish';
```

Например, эту командочку, можно было бы вызвать 
из любого удобного вам окружения.

Более подробно про команды рассказано тут:

- [FFmpeg Streaming Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide);
- [FFmpeg for streaming](https://sonnati.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/ffmpeg-%E2%80%93-the-swiss-army-knife-of-internet-streaming-%E2%80%93-part-iv/);
- [Онлайн вещание через Nginx-RTMP — несколько готовых рецептов](https://habr.com/en/post/174089/);
- [Про аргументы командной строки FFMpeg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519636/python-%D0%B8-ffmpeg-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81/551344#551344).

Можно пойти немного дальше, и использовать `nginx` c `nginx-rtmp-module`.

- [Streaming with nginx-rtmp-module](https://nginx-rtmp.blogspot.com/)
- [Getting started with nginx RTMP](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Getting-started-with-nginx-rtmp)
- [Attempting to Stream a Webcam to an RTMP Server](https://john.ly/stream-rtmp/)
- [`nginx-rtmp-module wiki: exec_push`](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#exec_push)

При этом `nginx.conf` всего скорее будет иметь вид:

```conf
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log debug;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        ping 30s;
        notify_method get;

        application src {
            live on;
            exec_push ffmpeg -i 'rtmp://src_stream:1935/play' -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv 'rtmp://dst_stream:1935/publish' 2>> '/var/log/ffmpeg-$name.log';
        }
    }
}
```

## Hа python

Решение на Python легко организовать через [PyAV](https://mikeboers.github.io/PyAV/). 
Это питонячие биндинги к `libav`.

О том что это такое и как это использовать можно почитать тут:

- [Про обработку видео в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519636/python-%D0%B8-ffmpeg-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81/551625#551625).

Про работу с RTMP в PyAV есть комментарий автора проекта:

- [Can I use PyAV to built a RTMP retransmit-server?](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyAV/issues/171).

### Пример

https://gist.github.com/w495/c4aa54e4783c2d3766407a5f4f7bc81d

```python
import av

# Откроем ресурс на чтение
input_resource = av.open(
    'rtmp://src_stream:1935/play'
)
# Откроем ресурс на запись.
output_resource = av.open(
    'rtmp://dst_stream:1935/publish',
    mode='w',
    format='flv'
)
# Список потоков входного ресурса: видео и аудио
input_streams = list()
# Список потоков выходного ресурса: видео и аудио
output_streams = list()
# Для входного и выходного ресурсов возьмём поток видео.
for stream in input_resource.streams:
    if stream.type == 'video':
        input_streams += [stream]
        # Создадим видео-поток для выходного ресурса. Кодек `h264`.
        output_streams += [output_resource.add_stream('h264')]
        break
# Для входного и выходного ресурсов возьмём поток аудио.
for stream in input_resource.streams:
    if stream.type == 'audio':
        input_streams += [stream]
        # Создадим аудио-поток для выходного ресурса. Кодек `aac`.
        output_streams += [output_resource.add_stream('aac')]
        break
# В этом списке будем хранить пакеты выходного потока.
output_packets = list()
# Применим «инверсное мультиплексирование». Получим пакеты из потока.
for packet in input_resource.demux(input_streams):
    # Получим все кадры пакета.
    for frame in packet.decode():
        # Сбросим PTS для самостоятельного вычислении при кодировании.
        frame.pts = None
        # Закодируем соответствующие кадры для выходных потоков.
        for stream in output_streams:
            if packet.stream.type == stream.type:
                output_packets += [stream.encode(frame)]
# Сбросим буфферы кодировщика. ??? Нужно ли ???
for stream in output_streams:
    output_packets += [stream.encode(None)]
# Для каждого пакета применим «прямое мультиплексирование».
for packet in output_packets:
    if packet: output_resource.mux(packet)
output_resource.close()
```

Это немного искусственный пример, и нужно помнить про некоторые особенности потокового видео. В частности, — оно потенциально бесконечно,
и это означает, что вы не сможете использовать списки пакетов и кадров (`list`).
В вашей задаче, всего скорее, будут нужны генераторы последовательностей и итераторы:

- [Python Practice Book: Iterators & Generators](https://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html);
- [Python wiki: Iterator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator);
- [Python wiki: Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).